# catalog_product_entity data not getting deleted completely

Tags: magento2, database, products

How to completely remove the catalog_product_entity table data.

I have deleted the values and again tried to import the csv, i get the ids starting from the last value(not from 1).

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried Changing the AUTO_INCREMENT id from database for phpmyadmin it should be in operations tab under the title of Table options.?